# Given n sets of integers, how to maximize the number of non overlapping sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, np-hard

Given n sets of integers, how to maximize the number of non overlapping sets?

For example, lets the given `sets` be,

```
{1,2,3}
{1,4,5}
{6,7,8}
{2,3}
{8,9}
{9}
```

Then the answer will be `4`,

```
 {1,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {2,3}, {9}
```

`{1,2,3}` and `{1,4,5}` can not consist of the non overlapping sets because 1 is common in both sets. Is it an NP heard problem? I will expect a little detail if there is an efficient solution for that problem.

**[N.B.]** The number of input sets can be upto **1000** with each set containing upto **1000** integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a Maximum Independent Set problem, where your sets correspond to nodes, and nodes corresponding to sets that share at least one element have an edge between them. It's NP-Hard and also hard to approximate to a constant factor.

You can still attempt to solve it, for example with integer linear programming:

```
maximize: sum x[i]

for each pair of sets (i,j) that overlap: x[i] + x[j] <= 1
```

`x[i]` is a boolean indicated whether the i'th set is part of the MIS that you're finding.

Comment: how do i check `bool + bool <= 1`? i am confused.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan you wouldn't, you give this to an existing solver, like GLPK, CPLEX, Gurobi.. if you mean how can booleans be summed at all, well, the standard way: false is 0, true is 1

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan to put it a bit differently, `x` is an array of booleans as per our interpretation. It's not a `bool[]`, it's actually a `float[]` for internal reasons - in fact while the solver is busy solving it, the partial solutions will have fractional values in  `x`. But the way the constraints are defined and how the result is interpreted, `x[i]` is effectively a boolean, only the values 0.0 (false = don't take this set) and 1.0 (true = this set is in the MIS) can appear in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the answer is simple: Assuming no set is empty, you can always find a maximum set where no set is a superset of one of the original sets - because a non-empty set and its superset or overlapping and cannot both be in the maximum set, and the superset can be replaced with the subset without creating any overlaps.

Here, {1, 2, 3} and {8, 9} can be excluded, and happily the remaining four sets are not overlapping.

Comment: can you please describe a little bit more with examples. thanks in advance.